# What BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC does?

Tags: c++, boost, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

I met in boost define

```
# define BOOST_PP_ENUM BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_ENUM_, BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_P, 4))
```

Could anyone explain what BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC does?
Can't find any description in documentation. 
What this macros actually for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC` help deduces the recursion level used in [Automatic Recursion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/reentrancy.html), by performing a binary search using a predicate. The first argument is the predicate and the second is the size to be searched. The predicate will be called as `pred(n)`, where `pred` is the predicate and `n` is the value.

The search must be ordered, so all values for which the predicate returns 0 must come before all values for which the predicate returns 1.

Since, the macro is used for [Automatic Recursion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/reentrancy.html), the predicate can not use any macro which employ automatic recursion.

For example, the predicate for repeat is defined like this:

```
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_P(n) BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_CHECK_, BOOST_PP_REPEAT_ ## n(1, BOOST_PP_NIL BOOST_PP_TUPLE_EAT_3, BOOST_PP_NIL))
#
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_CHECK_BOOST_PP_NIL 1
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_CHECK_BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1(c, m, d) 0
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_CHECK_BOOST_PP_REPEAT_2(c, m, d) 0
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT_CHECK_BOOST_PP_REPEAT_3(c, m, d) 0
```

So if `BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1` is called recursively, it won't expand. Thus when it concats with `BOOST_PP_REPEAT_CHECK_` it will expand to `BOOST_PP_REPEAT_CHECK_BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1`, which will expand to `0`. However if `BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1` is not being called recursively, then it will expand to `BOOST_PP_NIL`, which is then concated with `BOOST_PP_REPEAT_CHECK_` to produce `1`.

So the predicate is setup to detect if one of the `BOOST_PP_REPEAT_n` macros can expand. Then `BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC` will perform a binary search to find the first one that can expand. In the case of `BOOST_PP_REPEAT`, it will only search across 4 recursion levels, but other macros such as `BOOST_PP_WHILE` has a recursion depth up to 256.

Comment: Paul Fultz Thanks for you answer. It much clear for me now. Unfortunately not fully yet.
Maybe I steel miss the point.

For instance:
In boost declaration we have 
# define BOOST_PP_ENUM BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_ENUM_, BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_P, 4))

the BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_ENUM_, BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_P, 4)) always expands to BOOST_PP_ENUM_1

So, why just don't declare as
# define BOOST_PP_ENUM BOOST_PP_ENUM_1

Comment: If `BOOST_PP_ENUM` is called from a `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` macro it will not expand to `BOOST_PP_ENUM_1` like in the example here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/AppendixA-AnIntroductiontoPreprocessorMetaprogramming.html#horizontal-repetition

Comment: Paul Fultz thank you again.
I understood everything entirely because of you explanation.